# Charm DatePicker throws UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: gluon, javafxports, gluon-mobile

In the Google Play Console Crash Report section I discovered the following stacktrace for my app:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: 
  at java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.getMinusSign(DecimalFormatSymbols.java:300)
  at java.time.format.DecimalStyle.create(DecimalStyle.java:130)
  at java.time.format.DecimalStyle.of(DecimalStyle.java:119)
  at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.DatePicker$d.c(SourceFile:846)
  at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.DatePicker$d.<init>(SourceFile:679)
  at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.DatePicker$c.<init>(SourceFile:388)
  at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.DatePicker$b.<init>(SourceFile:220)
  at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.DatePicker.<init>(SourceFile:128)
  at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.DatePicker.<init>(SourceFile:115)
```

The issue occured on a Huawei P8 lite, Android 5.0.

Digging through the JDK and Android SDK sources I couldn't find any place, where this exception is raised, nor could I reproduce the error on a Huawei P9 lite, Android 6.0.

Could this error be caused by a possible dalvik implementation of `java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols`?

Comment: Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30655767/decimalformatsymbols-exception)

Comment: @jns - Did you get a fix for this?

Comment: no I dont think so